# Google App Script web app access denied when deployed and sharing executable link, without making the code edit access public

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on a project using google app scripts. When I deploy the project as web-app,and give the executable link to someone, they are not able to access it. Once I give permissions to the person to edit the code, he is able to access the web application,however by changing the url from
https://script.google.com/a/macros/blah.com/s/something/dev to https://script.google.com/a/macros/blah.com/s/something/edit?usp=drive_web, he can access the code itself and modify it.Is there any work around to this problem?

Comment: the url you show (https://script.google.com/a/macros/blah.com/s/something/dev) is not sharable unless you share the script itself (it's the so called "development url" used to test ) , the url you should give them ends with /exec and corresponds to the version you publish (the dev one corresponds to the latest saved script) . Moreover, see also the deployment instructions in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

When deploying as web app, in the same popup where you define the version, you also have to define if the script is going to run as yourself or as the user accessing the app. You also have to define the access level for the application from "only myself" to "anyone" or "anyone, even anonymous".

After changing that, the users with the link can access the webapp.